# Expand Records to create Edges for igraph

Tags: r, expand

I have a dataset that has multiple data points I want to map. iGraph uses 1-1 relationships though so I'm looking for a way to take one long record into many 1-1 records. For Example:

```
test <- data.frame(
drug1=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"),
drug2=c("P","O","R","T","L","A","N","D","R","A","D"),
drug3=c("B","O","R","I","S","B","E","C","K","E","R"),
age=c(15,20,35,1,35,58,51,21,54,80,75))
```

Which gives this output

```
   drug1 drug2 drug3 age
1      A     P     B  15
2      B     O     O  20
3      C     R     R  35
4      D     T     I   1
5      E     L     S  35
6      F     A     B  58
7      G     N     E  51
8      H     D     C  21
9      I     R     K  54
10     J     A     E  80
11     K     D     R  75
```

I'd like to make a new table with drug1-drug2 and then stack drug2-drug3 into the previous column. So it would look like this.

```
  drug1 drug2 age
1     A     P  15
2     P     B  15
3     C     R  20
4     R     R  20
5     E     L  35
```

drug2 is held in the drug1 spot and drug3 is moved to drug1. I realize I can do this by creating multiple smaller steps, but was was wondering if anyone new of a way to loop this process. I have up to 11 fields.

Here are the smaller steps.

```
a <- test[,c("drug1","drug2","age")]
b <- test[,c("drug2","drug3","age")]
names(b) <- c("drug1","drug2","age")

test2 <- rbind(a,b)

   drug1 drug2 age
1      A     P  15
2      B     O  20
3      C     R  35
4      D     T   1
5      E     L  35
6      F     A  58
7      G     N  51
8      H     D  21
9      I     R  54
10     J     A  80
11     K     D  75
12     P     B  15
13     O     O  20
14     R     R  35
15     T     I   1
16     L     S  35
17     A     B  58
18     N     E  51
19     D     C  21
20     R     K  54
21     A     E  80
22     D     R  75
```

Comment: Tags should be used to indicate languages, not annotations in the title.

Comment: Your transformation is very unclear to me. It sounds like you are moving everything to the drug1 column. Are you sure your sample output is correct? What would the total number of rows be after this transformation. If you can do it in small steps, perhaps post the code for that and we may be able to suggest a better way after seeing what you're really doing.

Comment: And this question doesn't really to seem to have anything to do with `igraph`, you're just manipulating a data.frame. I'm sure you plan to feed this into `igraph` but that doesn't seem relevant for answering your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tag suggestions. This dataset would be expanded to 22 records after. The idea is to overlap the records, so for drug1-drug3 you get two records. Drug1-drug2 drug2-drug3, and so on. If it was 4 fields it would be three fields: drug1-drug2, drug2-drug3, drug3-drug4 each with age being the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you have many fields, here's a helper function which can pull down the data into pairs.

```
pulldown <- function(data, cols=1:(min(attr)-1), 
  attr=ncol(data), newnames=names(data)[c(cols[1:2], attr)]) {

    if(is.character(attr)) attr<-match(attr, names(data))
    if(is.character(cols)) cols<-match(cols, names(data))

    do.call(rbind, lapply(unname(data.frame(t(embed(cols,2)))), function(x) {
        `colnames<-`(data[, c(sort(x), attr)], newnames)
    }))
}
```

You can run it with your data with

```
pulldown(test)
```

It has a parameter called `attr` where you can specify the columns (index or names) you would like repeated every row (here I have it default to the last column). Then the `cols` parameter is a vector of all the columns that you would like to turn into pairs. (The default is the beginning to one before the first attr). You can also specify a vector of newnames for the columns as they come out.

With three columns your method is pretty simple, this might be a better choice for 11 columns.

Comment: I really like this, very expandable. I don't fully understand the attribute paramater yet but I can really see how it will be useful. This is great.

Comment: @DanKS The attr parameter just let's you specify if there are any columns like "age" that should be repeated for every combination. So if you had age and gender as the last two columns, you could set `attr=c("age","gender")` and those values would be included on each row.

Comment: I think there is one change, the last line should read 'colnames<-' (data[, c(sort(x), attr)]. Is this correct?

Comment: @DanKS I'm not sure I understand the comment.

Comment: Sorry @MrFlick, I was trying to use the function on the dataset and it would only use it on the test dataset. When I changed test to data it seemed to work correctly.

Comment: @DanKS Ah, I see now. Yes, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more compact and a one-liner would be:

```
test2 <- rbind( test[c("drug1","drug2","age")], 
                setNames(test[c("drug3", "drug2", "age")], c("drug1", "drug2", "age")) 
      )
```

The `setNames` function can be useful when column names are missing or need to be coerced to something else.